# How much does the House Bipartisan Budget bill of 2013 increase spending in the next two years?

Tags: united-states, budget

The House recently passed a budget and ended the sequester cuts that under current law would extend into 2023. How much does this bill increase spending in the next two years? (in actual dollars and as a percentage of the budget)

Comment: http://www.glassmagazine.com/glassblog/fiscal-cliff-vs-household-budget-1310683 - The sequester is a tiny portion of the federal budget so halving the savings or even reversion all of the savings is still a tiny portion of the federal budget.  And its all debt because we do not have the revenue to support it.

Comment: What i find most troubling is that someone downvoted this. Is ending the sequester partisan? Are budget questions partisan?

Comment: (in actual dollars and as a percentage of the budget)

Comment: @Chad, which is partisan? Asking how much the budget has increased as a dollar amount, or asking how much the budget has increased as a percentage?

Comment: I never said it was partisan it is just not a good question.  For the most part our ideology aligns... you just choose angles to ask about that are not useful.

Comment: @user1873 I didn't down-vote, but I will say that this isn't a particularly interesting question.

Comment: @Chad, I suppose I could ask more interesting questions, but they get incessently donvoted. I personally think this is an interesting question. We already have one answer that says we decreased spending by 20%, the CBO that says it increases it by $48b, the Speaker of the House says it reduces the deficit.

Comment: @user1873 - Do not try to make apolitical point with your questions, do not try to slant or use provocative or contentious language in your questions.  Your questions should seek information that matters.  How much is not such a big problem as what is it in comparison to the total budget.  That makes it seem like you are trying to make a point.  I suspect that your SNAP question would have been highly voted had it been worded in a non partisan way that did not seem an attempt to vilify the people receiving it.

Comment: @Chad - this question was in no way slanted or provocative.

Comment: @DVK the previous comment was in response to the previous comment by user1873 not a comment on this question... please pay attnetion next time

Answer (score 2):

Per [this summary](http://politicalticker.blogs.cnn.com/2013/12/10/the-budget-deal-in-plain-english/):

> The deal caps the federal government's spending for Fiscal Year 2014 at $1.012 trillion and for Fiscal Year 2015 at $1.014

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_United_States_federal_budget), the government's 2013 discretionary spending (which is the comparable number) was $1.264 trillion, so this represents an ~20% **decrease** in federal spending.

Comment: any idea why the [CBO says it increases spending by $48 billion](http://www.cbo.gov/publication/44964)?

Comment: The government spends 2.6 trillion dollars a year.    the 1.012 is mandatory spending, not discretionary.  And incase you are wondering where the other 300 billion is, that is the cost of servicing the debt... which will increase by 48 billion more dollars this year due to this increase.

Comment: @Chad - my impression was that it was the reverse - the 1.012 was discretionary spending, which is what the budget is all about, and the rest was mandatory spending, which is unaffected by the budget.

Comment: @Bobson - Your linked document says otherwize

Comment: @Chad - Interesting... Something's not right with the numbers I'm looking at.  Because if it was capping mandatory spending at $1.012, that would represent a 50% cut from last year.  But based on Wikipedia, it's still a drop from last year.  Which means either Wikipedia is wrong or the article is using a different set of definitions. I'm going to have to dig into sources more.

Comment: @Bobson - It appears that the 1.012 number is a combination of the subset of items that includes both discretionary and mandatory spending that was reduced as part of the fiscal cliff.  It is not the whole of either.